# What should I do with this question?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529440/compiler-does-not-recognize-opencv-library) was a simple fix, answered in the comments. There was then a follow up question in the comments which was also fixed.

Should I write an answer that sums those up? Or flag the question to be closed?

Comment: What about the additional question in the comments?

Comment: The second comment is a straightforward typo, there's little value to keeping that around on SO. Surely there's a canonical duplicate for the first part?

Answer (score 1):

IMO the first solution is fine for the question.  The solution "don't use depricated stuff" is a valid answer and perhaps should be an answer.  The followup is really a second question, but this second question would be closeable by "off-topic: typographical error".

For this case, I'd say the original question can stay and should have the correct "don't use depricated stuff" as an answer (and perhaps pointing out the typo, if it's part of the code in the original question).  If the commenter won't create the answer, you are free to create it yourself (you can also make it community wiki if desired).  The followup does not belong in the question or even as a new question.